# Can anyone explain how the modified r-adding walk works?

Tags: discrete-logarithm

I was going through a paper titled [“Accelerating Pollard's Rho Algorithm on Finite Fields”](http://www.researchgate.net/publication/220479079_Accelerating_Pollard%27s_Rho_Algorithm_on_Finite_Fields) by Jung Hee Cheon et al. I understand the table(Ml) creation part of it, but after that I somehow fail to follow the rest.

Can anyone explain the modified r-adding walk to me?